# Aplicar rotação somente nos eixos X e Z

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou tentando rotacionar um objeto somente nos eixos X e Z, mantendo no eixo Y o valor original, mas desta forma a rotação simplesmente não funciona, ou fica totalmente desalinhada.

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, layerMask))
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, 
            Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal), 5F);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, rotation.z);
}
```